# Getting the same hashes on the web3 and Solidity side

Tags: solidity, web3js, solidity-0.6.x

How can I repeat this operation on web3.js and get the same hash

```
function test(uint a, uint b) pure public returns (bytes32) {
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(uint40(a), b);
    return hash;
}
```

- a - last block number
- b - is a large number like this: 58984214690415138970779328130626583025560028195120217299604246549340745742299